# Add contents to "div element having id or Class" inside TinyMCE editor

Tags: jquery, tinymce, content-editor

i have the following contents inside textarea/tinyMCE editor (id of my textarea is "notice":

```
<div ...>
  some contents here
</div>
<div id="myDiv">
Require to be updated from jQuery function
</div>
<div...> other div </div>
```

I am can put some contents here inside div element:(specially to the following div):

```
 <div id="myDiv"></div>
```

I can put contents here, if cursor is blinking here inside "myDiv", with the following code:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, parties);
```

using the above in the following javascript function with button onclick event:

```
function insert_contents(someContents){    
try {
     tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, someContents);
 } catch (e) {
    alert(e.message);
 }//catch
}//end function
```

My question: Is there anyway that i may put some contents inside "myDiv" div element and when if need it to remove may also remove the same contents from "myDiv" div without clicking the mouse there inside "myDiv"?
Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getContent()` to extract the entire contents of the editor and then modify it as you need.  You then would use `setContent()` to put the updated data back into the editor.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#getcontent
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#setcontent

Comment: This is good idea but i don't think it could be the optimal solution for this problem...